# Correct use of pointers with structures

Tags: c, pointers, struct

Is there any difference (performance / correctness / good practice) between:

**Option 1:**

```
typedef struct node{
    int value;
    struct node *next;
}*Node;

typedef struct linkedlist{
    Node head;
}*LinkedList;
```

**Option 2:**

```
typedef struct node{
    int value;
    struct node *next;
}*Node;

Node head = NULL;
```

And how can "double-pointer" scheme integrate both definitions?

Comment: Yes, `typedef`ing a pointer is almost always a very bad idea....

Comment: are you referring to option 1, `struct linkedlist`? And why is that a bad idea?

Comment: both the cases have that. `tyedef`-ed type does not carry the pointer notation, making the later usage less-readable.

Comment: To emphasise: **Never** `typedef` a pointer! It obfuscates the semantcs and is prone to errors. Is it really that complicated for you to add the `*` where you need a pointer? Re the question: comparing apples and oranges. These are two different approaches and opiniated/dependent on the application.

Comment: The struct in the first option (`Linked List`) is not usefull as it only contains one element. You should (in my opinion) use the second option and then keep a head pointer (or make it a double-linked-list). And as others allready noted, you should avoid typedef-ing pointers

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to what the comments say, it's not **always** a bad idea to `typedef` a pointer. There are some cases when you want to hide implementation details and provide functionality through a handle. In these situations it's quite common to see what's called an [opaque pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer) type.

Example:

In **LinkedList.h**

```
typedef void *LinkedList;
LinkedList LinkedList_Create();
void LinkedList_AddFirst(LinkedList list, void *element);
```

In **LinkedList.c**

```
struct linkedList {
    /* head, tail, size, ... */
};

LinkedList LinkedList_Create() {
    struct linkedList *plist = malloc(sizeof(struct linkedList));
    /* error checking, initialization */
    return plist;
}

void LinkedList_AddFirst(LinkedList list, void *element) {
    struct linkedList *plist = (struct linkedList *) list;
    /* your code here */
}
```

The downside of this approach is that you're required to explicitly cast the `typedef`'d pointer to your internal type but this will not result in worse performance since C does not provide runtime type checking.

From a best practices point of view, it's usually best to not `typedef` a pointer **if you don't need to hide implementation details**. Sure, it might make your code more verbose but that way you always know what type you're dealing with. Generally, a `typedef` should not hide the underlying type, but simply provide an alias for it.

If you're interested in knowing more about best practices in C, I refer you to Linux kernel's coding style guide, which you can find [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/CodingStyle).

Comment: You can achieve an opaque handle without hiding pointer semantics. That's in fact what the wikipedia page you posted to does. The struct it opaque in this idiom, not the pointer. And using `void*` instead of forward declaring a structure is also a needless hassle in most cases.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Although, my reasoning was that if you need to hide the underlying type you probably also want to hide the fact that it is a structure. Although, the approach described in the article sure has its advantages since it makes it possible for the caller to handle allocation.

Comment: Yes, you may want to completely hide the underlying type sometimes (that `void*` may in fact contain an int used in some internal map, instead of an actual pointer). **But** you shouldn't hide the type just for the sake of hiding the type. (Since you mentioned the Linux kernel, [Linus has an opinion on that as well](http://yarchive.net/comp/linux/typedefs.html), with his usual flair)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there seem to be a difference. First of all you haven't shown how you intend to use `LinkedList`, but anyway there is one more level of indirection needed to get to the data in the first option.

Let's assume that you in option one would use `LinkedList` as:

```
LinkedList lst;
```

then in order to get the first node in the list (or `NULL` if it's empty) you would have to use `lst->head`, while in the second option you just would use `head` directly. This would mean that the second option is slightly more efficient (in some cases).

However in the second option you have to send a pointer to `head` in order to pass it to a function that modifies the list as a whole. For example a function that empties a list must be able to modify the pointer to the head of the list in order to set it to `NULL` (yes it must also `free` the nodes, but that's beside the point). In the first option you can do this simply by `arg->head = NULL`, but in the second option you must send `Head*` to the function for it to be able to clear the head pointer. In this scenario there would be the same number of indirections to get to the elements.